# Ansible run playbook on IP in CLI, load variables from inventory

Tags: ansible

I normally run playbook like this: `ansible-playbook -i live nginx.yml`.

My hosts are defined in `live/inventory` and variables are defined in `live/group_vars`.

In need to run this playbook on a dynamic IP host where I need to provide IP as an argument in the CLI.

I can achieve it with this syntax: `ansible-playbook -i 113.45.97.11, nginx.yml`, however I lose the possibility of loading the `-i live` inventory with required variables.

Is there any way to load the variables from `live` directory?

I've tried: `--extra-vars "@live"`, but then I get

```
ERROR! an error occurred while trying to read the file '/home/tomek/data/bomcheck-ansible/live': [Errno 21] Is a directory: b'/home/tomek/data/bomcheck-ansible/live'
```

as it seems it can't read the directory.

What are the options? Basically I am trying to run playbook, along with the variables defined in the inventory, on a host defined dynamically via command line.

Comment: You should be able to load both inventories and take advantage of your group_vars => `ansible-playbook -i 113.45.97.11, -i live nginx.yml`. If this does not work exactly as you expect in your particular scenario, it's probably time to read about [dynamic inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) and use one of the available scripts/plugin or write your own.

Comment: Do you need all `live/group_vars` for this playbook? If not, you can load the specific vars file(s) you need with `--extra-vars` (can be specified multiple times). E.g. `-e @live/group_vars/group1.yml -e @live/group_vars/group2.yml`

Comment: The: `-i 113.45.97.11, -i live` approach would work, however it no longer loads anything except `group_vars/all` file or folder. This is because I've had to modify playbook to: `hosts: all` in order for this to work. This forces me to put all inventory in one basket, which wouldn't work as I have many other roles which shouldn't receive those variables.


The solution with loading each config file separately using the: `-e @live/group_vars/group1.yml` while tiresome and inflexible (as any change in the structure of inventory will impact this line) worked best.